# Saving 'raw' RGB bytes to image file

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I've got a weird case where I want to be able to write an `OpenCV.Mat` to disk WITHOUT it doing the automatic conversion from BGR (its internal representation) to RGB.

---

Maybe it's a case of premature conversion, but to avoid copying memory, I'm blitting some raw RGB data into a `new Mat`, and I don't really care that it interprets it as BGR because all the operations I'm performing with OpenCV are color-agnostic.

But when it comes to saving to disk, the default `Mat.Save` automatically converts 'back' to RGB, so my original RGB ends up backwards.

I know I could do a `CvInvoke.CvtColor` but that's back to copying memory *and* it irks me that Mat.Save is just going to convert it right back.

Is there a way to say just save my pixels to a usable file type, without having to copy them to another place in memory?

Comment: That seems a bit unlikely, although the exact format depends on the filename extension and you didn't provide any hints.  Don't forget that your machine is little-endian so if you are looking at raw bytes then it will look backwards.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a fairly esoteric solution to this, which probably won't help many people. But I happen to also be using the Stemmer Common Vision Blox library, and they have a handy `WrappedImage` type which can just 'wrap itself' around a block of pixel data and lets you tell it what's inside.

```
var size = mat.Cols * mat.Rows * mat.ElementSize;
WrappedImage.FromRgbPixels(mat.DataPointer, size, mat.Cols, mat.Rows, 
                           PixelDataType.UInt, 8, mat.NumberOfChannels, mat.Step, 1);
```

From there you can save it to whatever format without (I presume) the overhead of extra byte-by-byte conversions.